# High execution time for query

Tags: sql-server

Is there any way to reduce the execution time for the following query, It takes almost 2 minutes to execute. I have taken most of the keys and matching it with the tables. any suggestions is appreciated.

```
select cv.idcode as 'RHRN', 
cv.visitidcode as 'Encounter', 
cv.CurrentLocation , 
cpGrp.displayname  as 'AttendingGroup' ,
ar.Description as 'AlertDescription',
ar.createdwhen as 'AlertCreatedWhen',
bo.value as 'CreatinineLevel', 
bo.CreatedWhen as 'LabResultCreatedWhen',
ctv.value as 'ClassTypeValue', 
isnull (o.ordersetname,'') as 'OrderSetName', 
o.idcode as 'OrderID',
o.name as 'OrderName', 
me.DosageLow as 'Dose',
me.Uom as 'UOM', 
o.RequestedDtm as 'OrderRequestedDTM' , 
o.status as 'OrderStatus',
o.StopDtm 'OrderStopDTM',
me.ClientGUID

into #tmp1
from cv3order o (nolock) 
inner join cv3clientvisit cv (nolock) on  o.ClientGUID = cv.ClientGUID      ` `and o.ChartGUID = cv.ChartGUID
inner join cv3CareProviderVisitRole cpvrGrp (nolock) on ``cpvrGrp.clientVisitGuid = cv.guid and cpvrGrp.clientguid=cv.ClientGUID
inner join cv3CareProvider cpGrp (nolock)on cpGrp.guid = ` `cpvrGrp.providerGuid and cpvrGrp.rolecode = 'attending group'
inner join cv3alertRepository ar (nolock) on  ar.ClientVisitGUID = cv.guid 
inner join cv3CatalogClassTypeValue ctv (nolock) on  ctv.CatalogMasterGUID = o.OrderCatalogMasterItemGUID 
inner join cv3ClassType ct (nolock) on   ct.GUID = ctv.ClassTypeGUID 
inner join CV3MedicationExtension me(nolock) on me.guid = o.guid and me.ClientGUID=o.ClientGUID
inner join CV3BasicObservation bo (nolock) on bo.ClientVisitGUID = cv.guid and bo.ChartGUID=o.ChartGUID and bo.ClientGUID=o.ClientGUID
where ar.mlmname = 'AHS_AKI_Creatinine_Result' 
and ct.code = 'Acute Kidney Injury - AKI' and ctv.value in ('renally eliminated', 'nephrotoxicity')
and bo.ItemName = 'Creatinine LEVEL' 
and cv.CurrentLocation like 'schc%'
--and cv.CurrentLocation not LIKE 'FMC-55%'
--and cv.CurrentLocation not like 'FMC-37B%'
--and cv.CurrentLocation not like 'ACH%'

select 
RHRN, 
Encounter, 
max(LabResultCreatedWhen) as 'lastResultWhen'
into #tmp2     -- get the most recent lab result
from #tmp1
group by
RHRN, 
Encounter

select 
RHRN, 
Encounter, 
max(AlertCreatedWhen) as 'lastAlertWhen'
into #tmp3     -- get the most recent alert
from #tmp1
group by
RHRN, 
Encounter

select t1.*
from #tmp1 t1
inner join #tmp2 t2 on t1.LabResultCreatedWhen = t2.lastResultWhen
inner join #tmp3 t3 on t1.AlertCreatedWhen = t3.lastAlertWhen
order by t1.RHRN

drop table #tmp1
drop table #tmp2
drop table #tmp3
```

Comment: How many rows in each table?

Comment: CV3 Order cv3clientvisit 
i cv3CareProviderVisitRole c 
 cv3CareProvider  
 cv3alertRepository  
  cv3ClassType   
 CV3MedicationExtension    
 CV3BasicObservation

Comment: Not "how many tables" - I'm asking how many ROWS the query will output? 2 minutes might simply be a product of having a lot of data, or the indices either not being correct, or used in the correct way. I would avoid using so many #tmp tables if possible to start with.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?

Comment: You are joining 9 tables, with `where` clause against 5 of them. Are you expecting a very limited result (<10% of all data), or closer to a full dump of data? If limited, which of the 5 conditions are the single most limiting criteria. *That* is where your access plan should start. Does it, and are there good indexes to iterate through the data from there?

Comment: Here are the Table name  Clusterd Index no of rows in order for the 9 tables
cv3order   ClientGUID,ChartGUID 137855252
cv3clientvisit   ClientGUID,GUID 12120077
cv3CareProviderVisitRole   ClientGUID,ClientVisitGUID 39656153
cv3CareProvider   GUID 98154
cv3alertRepository    "ClientGUID,ChartGUID,PObjectGUID,MLMName,EventType,DestinationType,RuleGroup,RuleNumber,State,ObjectModifiedDtm 
" 3254686
cv3CatalogClassTypeValue   CatalogMasterGUID,ClassTypeGUID 9904
cv3ClassType   Code 402
CV3MedicationExtension   GUID 32446149
CV3BasicObservation  ClientGUID,ChartGUID,OrderGUID 207350983